# Jenkins requires TFS EULA acceptance

Tags: tfs, jenkins

I created a build job on Jenkins that is attached to a TFS server.  I used Team Explorer Everywhere to facilitate this.  The first time I ran the job,  I got the following message:

```
Error: You must accept the End User License Agreement for this product.
```

Which is fine, I ran the `tf eula` command and accepted the EULA.

The problem is that I'm still getting the same error when running the job.

Comment: Did you run the `tf eula` command as the user who runs the Jenkins server? Maybe that can make a difference.

Comment: I did run that command as the same user.

Comment: Sorry, then I am out of ideas. But worth a try. (We usually have this problem with ssh connections, at work.)

Comment: What is the contents of `C:\Users\[jenkinsuser]\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Configuration\TEE-Mementos\com.microsoft.tfs.client.productid.xml`?

Comment: <ProductIdData><eula-11.0-devpreview value="true"/></ProductIdData>

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution that I used to resolve the issue:

1. Set the Source Code Management to None
2. Add build step and choose Execute Windows batch command
3. type *tf eula -accept* in the command window
4. Run the build
5. Remove the above build step
6. Set Source Code Management back to Team Foundation Server and enter the details
7. Run the build again and it ran without error

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

To date we've had to perform this a couple times now, and so we've created a project which performs the acceptance of the EULA.

In the **Build** section of this new project, we have an **Execute Windows batch command** step which is as follows:

```
"C:\Team Explorer Everywhere for Team Foundation Server\TEE-CLC-11.0.0.1306\TEE-CLC-11.0.0\tf.cmd" eula -accept
```

Obviously you might need to change your path accordingly.

Now when we encounter this problem, we 'build' that project and it accepts the EULA for us.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Jenkins/TFS server.

I used:

`tf eula -accept`

Answer (score 0):

On mac make sure when you add the full path and choose Execute shell script
not just
tf eula -accept

I created a simple seperate build with only one Build task

**Execute shell**

> /Applications/TEE_CLC_14_0_1/tf eula -accept

Ran it

Then ran my larger build