# Jenkins exception : Run 'tf eula' to accept the End User License Agreement

Tags: jenkins, tf-cli

I'm trying to build a Visual Studio Solution(.sln) using Jenkins Plugin.

When I trigger the build I'm getting the below exception

```
Error: You must accept the End User License Agreement for this product
Run 'tf eula' to accept the End User License Agreement.
FATAL: Executable returned an unexpected result code [100]
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I run the tf eula to accept end user license agreement?

Any way to disable EULA by some configuration?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854412/jenkins-requires-tfs-eula-acceptance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tf eula -accept
```

search for tf.exe on slave machine